# Put rent costs as expense when working from home in UK

Tags: taxes, uk

I heard from someone that you can claim a part of your rent costs as an expense if you're working from home.

I work 100% from home and live in a flatshare with other people. I pay rent for my room £800/month.

From what I see here: https://www.gov.uk/simpler-income-tax-simplified-expenses/working-from-home it seems to me that those are the costs for utilities only. My utilities are included in the rent.

How much % can I claim from my rent costs?

Comment: In the United States, the IRS has limitations as to what can be classified as a "home office". In most situations it is difficult to claim rent/mortgage payments as a legitimate *business* expense since you'd be paying it anyway --- again, in the US.

Answer (score 3):

There are all sorts of considerations that you need to factor in...

I'd suggest that, as you are renting a room, you'd have difficulty in meeting the ["wholly and exclusively"](https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/business-income-manual/bim37007) test for part of it...

Secondly, you'd need to check that your rental agreement doesn't proscribe running a business... many do!

I'd suggest you can legitimately claim the flat rate allowance...

Answer (score 0):

### Separate facilities

In general, that works only if you can separate a part of your home that's wholly and exclusively used for business. E.g. if you have a separate "office room" then you might argue that the rent for that space is a business expense.

However, if you have a room where you both work and sleep in, that's not *solely* for the business, and thus you can't claim it as an expense.